# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException error in Windows 8 Visual Studio?

Tags: facebook, visual-studio, windows-8, argumentexception

I just downloaded a sample app for Windows 8 that should allow users to look through albums and upload pictures to facebook. When starting the app, I succeed in logging into my facebook, but right after logging in and displaying my profile picture, I get the following error:

"An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."

The problem seems to occur at this line: 
 await GetUserProfilePicture();

The app is here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Facebook-Photo-Albums-c9589b5a?SRC=VSIDE Would anybody be kind enough to download it and see what the problem is? You also need an App ID for it to function.

Answer (score 0):

The error is on line 81, file `FacebookInfoView.xaml.cs`. When `albuminfo` list has no values i.e. `count = 0` and if you call `albuminfo[0]`, it's surely gonna throw `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.